# Freemarker template not found, spring configuration

Tags: spring, freemarker

I am trying to use freemarker template using spring, my spring config is give below,

```
<bean id="freemarkerConf" class="org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean" >
    <!-- Turn this off to always load via SpringTemplateLoader -->
    <property name="preferFileSystemAccess" value="false"></property>
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="classpath:/WEB-INF/freemarker/alertmail/"></property>
</bean>
```

but for some reason I keep getting the following exception,

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Template mainMail.ftl not found.
at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:489)
at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:466)
```

My code is as below,

```
mailBody = FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(freemarkerConf.getTemplate("mainMail.ftl","UTF-8"), model);
```

My templates are located in a folder under the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure files are under: src/freemarker/alermail and then

```
    <bean id="freemarkerConf" class="org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean" >
        <!-- Turn this off to always load via SpringTemplateLoader -->
        <property name="preferFileSystemAccess" value="false"></property>
        <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="classpath:/freemarker/alertmail/"></property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Thanks but still the same issue

Comment: That didn't work either, so moved my files to src/freemarker and changed classpath to classpath:/. Loaded my file using "freemarker/alertmail/mailBody.ftl" and it worked. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Haha, i made the same change and it worked, and edited the answer. I was using FreeMarkerConfigurer though which is supported in web env.